# Delete all lines before a line that included specific word in a file by using php

Tags: php, file, delete-row

I need a simple code in php that can delete all lines before a line that included a specific word, for example this is contents of foo.txt:

```
.

.

eroigjeoj

dvjdofgj

dsfdsft

reytyjkjm

.

.

[DATA]

1,2,4

3,4,5

.

.

.
```

I want to delete all lines before line that included "[DATA]" and delete that line too.
and the result be a foo.txt with this content:

```
1,2,4

3,4,5

.

.

.
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet? You could use file_get_contents() to read the contents, use strpos() to find the position of [DATA], use substr() to read the contents beginning from [DATA] and write this substring back to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, maybe not the most efficient.

- Create a new text file (text2).

  ```
  $text2 = fopen("text2", "w");
  ```
- Initialise a boolean value to false.

  ```
  $hitWord = false;
  ```
- Read through original text file (text1) line by line until you hit
  the String '[DATA]', adding the subsequent lines to text2

  ```
  $handle = fopen("text1.txt", "r");
  if ($handle) {
     while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
         if($hitWord){
             fwrite($text2, $line . "\n");
         }else{
             if(strpos($line,'[DATA]') !== false){
                 $hitWord = true;
             }
         }
     }
     fclose($handle);
  } else {
  // error opening the file.
  }
  ```
- Delete text1 using `unlink($text1)`  // you will need path
- Rename text2 to text1 using `rename()` function.

**ALTERNATIVELY**

You could use the same approach above. Except instead of editing a new text file, edit a new String and just replace all the lines in `text1` with this string at the end of the program.

This would save you having to create/delete/edit new files. Make sure new line is used correctly